# How to add Custom properties in Alfresco using dotCMIS 1.0 for Visual studio2010

Tags: vb.net, alfresco, dotcmis

I am working on ALfresco using dotCMIS with Visual Studio 2010. When I try to add a new document the system will accept only few properties like the below ones only.

```
properties(PropertyIds.ObjectTypeId) = "cmis:document" 
properties(PropertyIds.Name) = txtDocTitle.Text
```

I want to add few more properties like Description, Client Name, DocID and Tag Name. How can I add custom properties on Alfresco using dotCMIS 1.0 for .NET appliction?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but rather cumbersome to handle properties of aspects with DotCMIS. Have a look at PortCMIS, the successor of DotCMIS (https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/portcmis.html). The API is pretty similar and it supports CMIS 1.1. Aspects are modeled as secondary types and setting secondary type properties is simple.